# Xcode CoreData: Error when trying to load an empty array from a fetch request

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am currently making a Course/Homework Tracker App that tracks your classes. I have a tab that displays the courses that the user has created. When the user first uses the app, however, they do not have any courses saved, so this tab is empty. The page should be like this...

[image]

However, I am currently getting an error when I use ForEach loop to display empty results.

```
struct MyCourses : View {
  @FetchRequest(entity: Category.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: 
  \Category.title, ascending: true)], animation: .spring())

  var categoriesResults : FetchedResults<Category>

  ...

  ForEach(categoriesResults, id: \.self) { category in      // error here
    CategoryBoxView(category: category)
}
```

CategoryBoxView...

```
struct CategoryBoxView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
var context: NSManagedObjectContext

var category : Category!
```

The error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
How do I go about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by preventing fetching if CoreData doesn't have any information.

Here is my code

```
func loadIsCurrent() -> [CurrentTrainingPlan] {
        
        var _runs : [CurrentTrainingPlan] = []
        let context = CoreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CurrentTrainingPlan> = CurrentTrainingPlan.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "index", ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(key: "isCurrent", ascending: true)]
        
        do {
            let sessions = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if(sessions.count > 0) {
                _runs = sessions
            }
        } catch {
            print("Something happened while trying to retrieve tasks...")
        }
        return _runs
    }
```

Here I am fetching results from my running sessions as you can see it only does fetch if number of sessions saved in CoreData Is greater than 0